# Resources$NotFoundException. Can't open PDF from /res/raw

Tags: java, android, pdf

Tell me. There is a resource in res /raw /template.pdf. Pdf opens, works, but when you try to open from the application:

```
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.template);
```

I get the error:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/raw/template.pdf from drawable resource ID #0x7f0e0000
```

I tried to open like this (I still get the same error):

```
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(context.getResources().getIdentifier("template", "raw", context.getPackageName()));
```

What to do?

I did `Clean and Rebuild Project`, `Invalidate cache and restart` and renaming, copying file, nothing can help me.

Comment: does `openRawResource()` work or it fails too?

Comment: @pskink `openRawResource()` works

Comment: @pskink I did not help either

Comment: @pskink I did so
```String pathOfPDF = "android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.template;
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(pathOfPDF);
            ParcelFileDescriptor descriptor = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");```
But now i get the error:
```java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resource does not exist: android.resource://europrotocol.appcore.com.europrotocol/2131623936```
File in directory /res/raw exists

Comment: @pskink I did it, but I get all the same mistake

Comment: @pskink I tried to open another resource, all the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Do you try this

Use this to access the file:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("template","raw", getPackageName());
```

Then top open the file content or to create a file form it u need an Input stream this will work like this:

```
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier("template", "raw", getPackageName()));
```

Note: I'm supposing you are in a context. Other wise use `context.` with the code.

Comment: Thanks, it's works, but how I can get `FileDescriptor` for `PdfRenderer` from this `InputStream`? And I would ask: why `openRawResource()` works, but `openRawResourceFd()` not?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get your path following way:

```
pathOfPDF = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.template;
```